# Can we read from file /dev/input/eventX from signed system app?

Tags: android, linux, low-level

I am able to read file /dev/input/eventX on my rooted device. I wonder, if i can able to do same on signing my app as system app? Please help!!!

Comment: I think yes, but it does make sense only if you are going to make your own firmware (ROM), and place a system app in it

Comment: yea..i want to make app specifically  for my ROM. I guess using some system permission i can do that. Someone please guide.

Comment: The question is interesting, but I don't think that you can find any experienced ROM developer here, or anyone who is proficient in system permissions. I suggest you to search over the http://forum.xda-developers.com/, and post a question there

Comment: Thanks @VladMatvienko for guiding.. i'll look there :)